# Haskell Homework - Decimal List [Int] -> Int

Tags: haskell, fold

The assignment is to define function `decimal :: [Int] -> Int` in which a list of positive ints is to give the decimal number [image: Sigma function] so that the list `[1,4,3,1,9]` is to return the `Integer` 14319. I am to use the `fold` function.

I don't really have good idea to start here, so I just need a push in the right direction, but I was thinking about the Horner-scheme. Thanks!

Comment: show and read no, ++ yes

Comment: I don't see how [1,4,3,19] produces 14319 using that formula. I can agree if you missed a comma between 1 and 9 in 19.

Comment: whoops, yeah i meant 1,9

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is my variant

```
import Data.List
decimal :: [Int] -> Int
decimal xs = foldl' (\sum (pos,x) -> (sum + x*(10^(l-pos)))) 0 $ zip [1..] xs where
            l = length xs


*Main> decimal [1,4,3,1,9]
14319
```

In `Haskell`, you have really powerfull weapon - functions for lists processing. One of these functions is `foldl` (we use strict version of `foldl`, `foldl'`) It's type

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

This functions takes thre arguments, an accumulating agrument, a list processed, and, the most interest, 
the function that perform any operation with accumulator and list element and returns the result. Fold is really significant function so you should read detail [manual](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) about it.
But, there is a problem, we have three variables it our equation: list element processed (`x`), total list length (`n`) and position of processed element (`k`). But we can traverse to `foldl` only one element.
How can we traverse position of each element? Let's form tuples from `Int` where first element is a position, and second is a value. It is a standard trick, `zip` function helps us:

```
zip [1..] [1,4,3,4,6]
[(1,1),(2,4),(3,3),(4,4),(5,6)]
```

Than we pass our list of tuples into `foldl` function, and `foldl` call `lambda function` `(\sum (pos,x) -> (sum + x*(10^(l-pos))))` for each element of list, summing result in `sum`

Comment: 1. this is a homework, so giving away a piece of code is not nice; 2. you should improve the function to get rid of exponentiation on every step

Comment: Agreed - this is a somewhat round and about way of doing it! You could do it just as well with toNum = foldl1 (\a b -> a * 10 + b).

Comment: @Tetigi I know that `foldl1 (\a b -> a * 10 + b)` is work, but I guess that topic starter have to use formula above explicitly

Answer (score 5):

In the fold, you start from the left and move towards the right. As you consume the next element from the list, you multiply what you already had by 10 and add the new element to that.

So if you seed the foldl with 0, and had [1,2,3], your function would multiply current (0) by 10 (also 0), then add 1. Moving on, multiply current (1) by 10 (to get 10) and add 2 (12). Then finally for 3, 12 * 10 = 120, 120 + 3 = 123.

That should be pretty easy to code up :)

Comment: Easily doable in one line with a lambda function. You can also use foldl1 instead of foldl and then you don't even need the 0!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this equation would guide you.

[image: S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n x_k 10^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k 10^{n-k} + x_n = 10\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k 10^{(n-1)-k} + x_n = 10S_{n-1} + x_n]

Comment: Alright, this is indeed useful. Thank you and I will try to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework, let's stop at the suggestion that you expand this expression for some list, and try to extract a recurrent relationship:

x_0*10^n+x_1*10^(n-1)+...+x_n*10^0 = (((x_0*10+x_1)*10+x_2)...)*10+x_n

If you compare this to folds, you will see one fold matches this pattern for a particular function of two arguments.